# How do I get VS2010 to generate Resources.Designer.cs with a public constructor instead of internal?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Each time I edit a resource in **resources.resx**, Visual Studio regenerates Resources.Designer.cs with an **internal** constructor.

I need this constructor to be **public**. Is there a way to adjust this?

Answer (score 9):

Follow these steps:
Open the project properties (i.e. the one for which Resources you want to be public).
Select the Resources tab. Next to the Top you should be able to see the Access Modifier DropDownList and there you can choose the Internal or the Public.
That is it :)

Comment: Hmm, appears this is not an option for Silverlight control libraries, since I don't have a Resources tab in Project Properties.

Comment: Well but still when editing the resource you get alomost the same window with that top area and there is that Access Modifier located.

Comment: Ah, good tip. Interestingly enough, it's set to Public and generates Internal :-/

Comment: Yeah, you're right :( Though now you can access all the resources from outside of an assembly they originate from :) is this not what you're trying to achieve? You access the resources by static properties which now should be public.

Comment: In this case, it's causing Silverlight Prism module instantiation to fail. Not sure if there's a way to adjust that, but I guess I may have to write this one off as a VS bug..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it (public constructor) is possible in Visual Studio by default, but you can try to solve your problem using [Friend Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0tke9fxk(VS.80).aspx) or by making a wrapper class.